# start postgres server and psql via batch

Tags: postgresql, batch-file

I would like to execute the following commands on Windows by batch instead of manually (cmd):

```
K:
cd db\pgsql\bin
pg_ctl -D "K:\db\pgsql\data" start
psql -U postgres -W -d mydb
```

If I just copy it to a `.bat`, it is starting the server and connect via psql, but I can´t execute `\q` to exit psql and stop the server. Is there a better way?

Comment: Do you want to run SQL statements manually or are there some predefined statements you want to execute?

Comment: Manually SQL and psql commands

Comment: Then you have to manually enter `\q`, `psql` closes and the execution of your batch file will continue. Where is the problem?

Comment: When I enter ```\q``` nothing happens and cmd hangs up, I can´t enter anything more, just ```CTRL + C```

Comment: If you want to stop the server, add a line to do that.

Comment: But what if I just like to exit ```psql``` and execute another command e.g. ```pg_dump```? Or is the only opportonity ```\! pg_dump```